# Perl IF statement not matching variables in REGEX

Tags: perl

```
my $pointer = 0;
foreach (@new1)
{
       my $test = $_;
       foreach (@chk)
       {
               my $check = $_;
               chomp $check;
               delete($new1[$pointer]) if ($test =~ /^$check/i);
       }
       $pointer++;
}
```

The if statement never matches the fact that many entries in the @new1 array do contain $check at the start of the array element (88 at least).
I am not sure it is the nested loop that is causing the problem because if i try this it also fails to match:

```
foreach (@chk)
{
        @final = (grep /^$_/, @new1);
}
```

@final is empty but I know at least 88 entires for $_ are in @new1.

I wrote this code on a machine running Windows ActivePerl 5.14.2 and the top code works. I then (using a copy of @new1) compare the two and remove any duplicates (also works on 5.14.2). I did try to negate the if match but that seemed to wipe out the @new1 array (so that I didn't need to do a hash compare).

When I try to run this code on a Linux RedHat box with Perl 5.8.0 it seems to struggle with the variable matching in the REGEX. If I hard code the REGEX with an example I know is in @new1 the match works and in the first code the entry is deleted (in the second one value is inserted in @final).

The @chk array is a listing file on the web server and the @new1 array is created by opening two log files on the web server and then pushing one into the other.

I had even gone to the trouble of printing out $test and $check in each loop iteration and manually checking to see if any of the the values did match and some of them do.

It has had me baffled for days now and I have had to throw the towel in and ask for help, any ideas?

Comment: I notice you are using `chomp` on the value from `@chk`, but not the value from `@new1`, and you originally developed this code on Windows. How are the two lists populated initially? If the strings in `@chk` have Windows line endings, the `chomp` under Linux will only remove the '\n', not '\r\n'.

Comment: [delete](http://p3rl.org/delete) on arrays is deprecated. If you want to remove an element, use [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice). If you want to undefine an element, use [undef](http://p3rl.org/undef).

Comment: @chepner - Bingo, I was labouring under the impression that chomp would remove any line endings it finds. A simple - $check =~ s/\r\n//g; instead of chomp $check; fixed the problem!

Comment: See my answer for a way to make `chomp` remove "\r\n", but the `s//` operator is fine and probably a little safer.

Comment: Calling `delete` on an array is virtually always the wrong thing to do; doing so upon the very array you’re currently iterating over is even worse. Use `delete` on hashes and `pop/shift/splice` on arrays, and pretend that’s all there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tested by user1568538, the solution was to replace

```
chomp $check;
```

with

```
$check =~ s/\r\n//g;
```

to remove Windows-style line endings from the variable.

---

Since `chomp` removes the contents of the input record separator `$/` from the end of its argument, you could also change its value:

```
my $pointer = 0;
foreach (@new1)
{
   my $test = $_;
   foreach (@chk)
   {
       local $/="\r\n";
       my $check = $_;
       chomp $check;
       delete($new1[$pointer]) if ($test =~ /^$_/i);
   }
   $pointer++;
}
```

However, since `$/` also affects other operations (such as reading from a file handle), perhaps it is safest to avoid changing `$/` unless you are sure if it is safe. Here I limit the change to the `foreach` loop where the `chomp` occurs.

Comment: You’re still using `delete` on an array.  And you’re still changing the array out from under yourself.  *¡No me gusta, señor!*

Comment: You're right about changing the array by using `$_`, fixing. However, I'm going to leave the `delete` for this answer. The original question was about a regex match failing, and that's been fixed. Since `delete` has slightly different semantics than either `slice` or `undef` (`slice` always shrinks the array, `undef` never does, and `delete` will shrink the array only if the last item is deleted), I think it's beyond the scope of this question to determine the correct replacement.

Answer (score 1):

No knowing what your input data looks like, using `\Q` might help:

```
if ($test =~ /^\Q$check/i);
```

See [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. However, you may be trying to only get those elements for which there is no match or vice versa. Adapt the code below for your needs

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my @item  = qw(...); # your @new?
my @check = qw(...); # your @chk?
my @match;
my @nomatch;

ITEM:
foreach my $item (@item) {

   CHECK:
   foreach my $check (@check) {
      # uncomment this if $check should not be interpreted as a pattern,
      # but as literal characters:
      # $item = '\Q' . $item;
      if ($item =~ /^$check/) {
         push @match, $item;
         next ITEM; # there was a match, so this $item is burnt
          # we don't need to test against other $checks.
      }
   }

   # there was no match, so lets store it:
   push @nomatch, $item.
}

print "matched $_\n" for @matched;
print "didn't match $_" for @nomatch;
```

Your code is somewhat difficult to read. Let me tell you what this

```
foreach (@chk) {
   @final = (grep /^$_/, @new1);
}
```

does: It is roughly equivalent to

```
my @final = ();
foreach my $check (@chk) {
   @final = grep /^$check/, @new1;
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
my @final = ();
foreach my $check (@chk) {
   # @final = grep /^$check/, @new1;
   @final = ();
   foreach (@new) {
      if (/^$check/) {
         push @final, $_;
         last;
      }
   }
}
```

So your @final array gets reset, possibly emptied.

Comment: the code works it was a simple schoolboy error around the miss use of chomp.